# New Project: Android resource compilation failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

```
**Error is Here:**

Android resource compilation failed
Output:  F:\UserApp\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Command: C:\Users\iAngkur\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\a5439741e2d1dbefbffc15295f5d15fb\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        F:\UserApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        F:\UserApp\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #2
```

After creating a new project, the color.xml file had some unknown characters. Then I added this code manually.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

    <color name="colorPrimary">#0a091b</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#070716</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

</resources>
```

Depedencies code is here.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Look at "ic_launcher.xml"

Comment: You need to post the content of mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems related to this file `app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml:1`

Could you try to update it like this (change drawable to your own icon_launcher):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <background android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
  <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```